Identify Duplicate Value in Integration Procedure
I have an integration procedure which receives an array containing several listItems, in case any of the listItems have the same productId I need to recalculate a value.
Input for the IP looks like this
"ListItems":
        [
            {"ProductId": "01t9O000DgvQAG", "OtherField": "Value1"},
            {"ProductId": "01t9O000DgvQAG", "OtherField": "Value2"},
            {"ProductId": "01t9O000DgkQAH", "OtherField": "Value3"}
        ]

I've tried using the ListAction, which is great for merging but doesnt seem to help me by identifying that there's a identical Id, and if so which one.
How would I go about identifying that the array contains a listItem with an identical Id?

I managed to get a solution using a combination of a Data Mapper Transform wrapped in an Integration Procedure.
The Data Mapper Transform does all the logic, as I have found its formula capabilities are much easier to work with than anything else.
The Data Mapper Transform:

Receives the original list together with a ProductId which will be our SearchKey,
Uses FILTER(LIST(%ListItems%), 'ProductId == "' + SearchKey + '"') to create a new List with all the List Entries for a given SearchKey
Counts the entries in the new List
Returns the count as well as the SearchKey


The Integration Procedure is used to feed each ProductId to the Data Mapper Transform as a SearchKey using a loop block.
It then returns the ProductId that has a count greater than 1.

When there is a duplicate in the List, the Integration Procedure returns:

I also added some logic that it will return null if no duplicate is found:

You can then use the response of the Integration Procedure to determine if there was a duplicate or not.
Note though that this will return the last duplicate ProductId.
So if there are two pairs of duplicate ProductIds, the Integration Procedure will return the last pair in the List.
This POC can be found in this Github Repo. You can use this manifest file to deploy it to your org if you want.
Good luck!

This sounds great. Could you possibly provide the poc as a datapack? I'm having issues deploying it to test it in my org.

@jvb sure: https://github.com/sfadriaan/Stack-Exchange-Answers/tree/main/425660 If this was helpful, I would really appreciate it if you can mark my answer as correct.
